# How to know each register value instruction by instruction in a binary using radare2?

Tags: binary-analysis, radare2, malware, pintool

As I am using the radare2 for reverse engineering, I find it very difficult to get all the register values instruction by instruction with the help of the Radare2 tool. Could someone please help me to identify the solution for the above said with the help of Radare2?

If it is not possible with radare2, could you please suggest some other tool that can do it (apart from OllyDbg. Since it is available in GUI mode, I need some tool that can be handled from the terminal (CLI))

Comment: got to visual mode i think VV you should see tegisters printed

Answer (score 1):

As i commented use visual mode to see all registers

```
radare2 file.exe
ood 
vv
f7 / s
```

[image]

EDIT

that is not a realistic expectation
are you going to keep on single stepping for eternity ?
what are you trying to do ?

```
use e log.level = debug 
e.logfile = somepath
```

and execute `pd1@rip;ds 1; drd;`

which will log all the changed registers between each command to a file of your choice but beware this is impractical

Comment: Dear @blabb,  thank you for your answer. Could you please tell me how we can save these register values instruction-wise for all instructions?

Comment: that is kinda impractical you would be stepping in thousands if not millions of instructions to get past a single funnction refine your strategy  if you insist  set e log.level=debug and keep executing pd1@rip;ds1;drd; to disassemble 1 step step in 1 step and print the changed registers between 1 step

Comment: Got it, but is there a way where we can stop debugging after some time ex: 2mins or so?

Comment: putting a hammer on the head of nail may be (CTRL+C) ??  break your flow into manageable parts , set breakpoints trace between breakpoints  , refine your breakpoints  brute forcing step by step is never a good strategy